# VM Snapshot recovery of MOSS 2007?

Tags: 2007, central-administration, backup, virtual-machine, disaster-recovery

Has anybody ever recovered their MOSS 2007 farm from VM snapshots from the night prior?

MOSS VM, 2 WFE VMs and a SQL 2005 blade.

Say SharePoint becomes corrupted and  we just can't fix it. Any good recovery option if we have SQL full backups and VM snapshots of the MOSS and 2 WFEs from the night prior?  These backups finished at different times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SnapShot recovery not supported for the SharePoint because their are many things which are time sensitive align with Config db, which upset with snapshot recovery. You should read the below blogpart 1 and 2, which explain the why it is not good idea. Another thing, you dont have the backup at the same time which again cause many problems.

[SharePoint vs. Snapshots](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mossbiz/archive/2013/01/14/sharepoint-vs-snapshots.aspx)

What I would do (as we have the sql backup of content DB)

- rebuild the farm(same version level)
- create the Web Application and SSP etc
- restore the Content DB and attach to web app
- run full crawl on search

Comment: i expected that answer.  The question was more for DR purposes.  We are currently on MOSS 2007 SP2 and unsupported by Microsoft unless we patch up.   We also have a lot of third party solutions like Fab40 we would need to install Question, what if we built a brand new two server farm at MOSS 2007 SP4, could content DBs from SP2 restore into that? Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can restore the dB from lower build numbers, once you attach it will upgrade.